# Why is my Canon 600D not turning on?

Tags: troubleshooting, repair, canon-600d, power

My Canon 600D was working fine till the last two months when issues started rising. When I switch it on, I don't see the red blinking light and it's not turning on. The last time, I removed the battery and memory card, and after some time it worked fine. What might be the possible reason for this malfunction? And how much will it cost to fix this?

I haven't tested it with a different battery, and I used a micro SD-to-SD adapter but the camera got super hot, and the memory card adapter got hot as hell.

Comment: Are you able to test with a different battery?

Comment: no i didnt test it with different battery and i used a micro sd to sd adapter but the camera got super hot. and the memory card adapter was hot like hell

Comment: I just found out something new. The camera turns on without any prob when memory card is not inserted. But doesn't turn on when memory card is inserted. There is no problem with the battery or camera's working. I guess the problem is either with memory card or memory card slot. Any clue about this ?

Comment: I have the same problem with my 600D. I don't know what does this issue depend on, but nowadays my camera does not turn on. Sometimes it happened before, but nowadays it does not work. Only after trying a lot of removing the card, the lens and the battery helped; but the last time when it has turned on I opened the card slot and the device immediately stopped working. I closed the card slot and it did not started to work. Turned it off, turned it on; removed the battery and still nothing happened. After that I noticed a strange clack coming from the inside of it, then I removed the battery aga

Answer (score 7):

If I were you, I'd go ahead and buy another battery [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064FS7HI). If a new battery fixes it, dispose of your old one, and you're good for $15. If not, it might be an internal problem and you'd probably have to send it to Canon.

**Edit** Per OP's comment, the problem seems to have been narrowed down to whether the memory card is inserted or not.

Try it with a new memory card.  Something reliable, like [a Sandisk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0143RT8OY).  Again, if that doesn't fix your problem, you might have to send it to Canon for servicing.  Prices can vary, so a quick phone call to Canon's customer service (1 (800) 652-2666) would be the most reliable source.

Comment: Hey there, good answer (+1). I edited it to remove the link to the comment. Comments are really second class citizens here and might get deleted any time without notice. No need to "trace back" to where you posted this content the first time =)

Comment: I just found out something new. The camera turns on without any prob when memory card is not inserted. But doesn't turn on when memory card is inserted. There is no problem with the battery or camera's working. I guess the problem is either with memory card or memory card slot. Any clue about this ?

Comment: @null - actually, that was a link to a meta post :)  Either way, it doesn't add a ton, I guess.

Comment: @user3196569 I edited my answer.  Try using a different memory card.  If that doesn't work, I think you might be about due for a call to canon's customer service.  You can google it, or use the number I posted above (I googled it :-) )

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with my 70D suddenly not wanting to work properly and then complaining about the SD-card.  It turned out to be one of the thin plastic separators between the connectors that had broken off at one end and interfered with the connectivity.  Removing that fixed it.

You may have a similar problem, but with the "Do not work without card inserted" setting active in the camera.