# My Canon 600D stopped working as I inserted Microphone

Tags: canon-600d

My 600D Canon camera stopped working immediately I inserted a Microphone to start recording, I have changed batteries and Memory cards yet it has refused to come on.

What do I do please?

Comment: Can you provide photo of microphone connector?

Comment: See also: [Why is my Canon 600D not turning on?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/84093) The suggestion there seems to be to try without any memory card inserted, though it's not related to the microphone jack.